# Comparing unique values across multiple data frames in R

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe, loops, count

I have 3 data frames (df1,df2,df3), each with 1274 rows and 2192 columns. I want to count the number of occurrences when the value of a cell matches 0.968 in df1, 0.972 in df2 and 0.909 in df3. Note that the cells have to be in the exact same location (same row and column number).

Example,

df1

```
| 0.968 | 0.526 |
| 0.938 | 0.632 |
| 0.873 | 0.968 |
```

df2

```
| 0.342 | 0.972 |
| 0.545 | 0.231 |
| 0.434 | 0.972 |
```

df3

```
| 0.673 | 0.812 |
| 0.128 | 0.764 |
| 0.909 | 0.909 |
```

The answer should return: 1

Is using a loop the best option to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```r
sum((df1 == 0.968) *  (df2 == 0.972) * (df3 == 0.909))

#> [1] 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try the code below

```
sum(df1==0.968 & df2 == 0.972 & df3 = 0.909)
```

If you would like to index the TRUE values, you can use `which`

```
which(df1==0.968 & df2 == 0.972 & df3 = 0.909, arr.ind = TRUE)
```

Comment: This works for identifying the appearances of the values in data frames, but I think he also wants them to be in the same location. So, maybe first change to a logic vector and then index the TRUE locations.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I want them to be in the same location. I can change it to a logic vector, but how do I index the TRUE locations?

Comment: @Bloxx see my update

Comment: @ajides see my update